# install oracle java sdk in ubntu - configuration problem - runs only with sudo priviledge

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am trying to to configure java sdk on ubuntu 12.04.
I ha/ve copied the jdk folder to `/usr/lib/java` 
and made a link as "sudo ln -s -b /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac /etc/alternatives/javac" and "sudo ln -s -b /usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac /bin/bin/javac"

but when i try to run command "javac" it doesn't run. however it runs as "sudo javac" correctly. how can i make it run without sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution. Just need to change the permission of the /java and its sub folders to allow access to the inner-files.